# Error when trying to update values in database

Tags: c#, database, sql-update, insert-update

I have the following c#/Query:

```
TrackDuration =TimeSpan.Parse( Request.Form["TrackDuration"].ToString());
string InsertQuery = string.Format("UPDATE tblTracks SET  TrackLength={0}, TrackDuration='{1}', TrackName='{2}',TrackDescription='{3}',TrackMap='{4}',DifficultLevel={5},OverallHeight={6},IsCircular='{7}', ForBeginners='{8}',StartPoint='{9}',ParkingPlace='{10}',SeasonOfYear={11},TrackLocation={12}, Images='{13}' WHERE UserID={14}",
                                                                      TrackLength, TrackDuration, TrackName, TrackDescription, TrackMap, DifficultID, OverallHeight, IsCircular, ForBeginners, StartPoint, ParkingPlace, SeasonID, AreaID, ImageList, UserID);
```

But I got this error message:

> Syntax error in UPDATE statement
>
> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

I realy tried to solve this, but I can't.

How can I fix this problem?

Update:

This is the value of the Query:

```
UPDATE tblTracks SET  TrackLength=35, TrackDuration='02:30:00', TrackName='45',TrackDescription='<p>sometext.</p>
',TrackMap='f',DifficultLevel=3,OverallHeight=450,IsCircular='true', ForBeginners='false',StartPoint='<p>קיבוץיסעור </p>
',ParkingPlace='<p>כניסה לקיבוץ יסעור</p>
',SeasonOfYear=1,TrackLocation=3, Images='' WHERE UserID=1
```

The sql values types are:

```
TrackLength = number ; TrackDuration = date/time ; TrackName= string ;TrackDescription= string; TrackMap = string; DifficultLevel=number;OverallHeight=number;IsCircular=true/false;ForBeginners=true/false;
StartPoint=string; ParkingPlace=string; SeasonOfYear=number; TrackLocation=number;Images=string
```

Comment: What about the 'near' suggestion when SQL DBMS throws an error? You should check your column (in the UPDATE query) data type, which 'text' (varchar, char,...) should be included in a pair of single quote, I think you should apply this rule on all the columns. The last is what about Image column? Is that binary/image or simply type of text which stores the image paths?

Comment: The last value us string. The error is in the "TrackDuration" Which is Time, I have no Idea why...

Comment: Please parameterize your queries.

Comment: Hey, If so, I'm sure you pass an incorrect format of datetime value into the UPDATE query at the TrackDuration column, please give some example of that value which you setup/prepare for the query.

Comment: It would be obvious if you would show the formatted value of `InsertQuery` instead of formatting line.

Comment: All the pramater's type is string

Comment: Well, if so you should add single-quotes to all the values passed in, if not it won't work.

Comment: so, what's the value of `TrackDuration`? don't keep us guessing

Comment: He've just said it's datetime, but then he adjusted to 'string', I don't really understand what exactly the fact is.

Comment: I updated my question, the 'TrackDuration'  is a TimeSpan type

Comment: Is TrackDuration (in SQL server table) type of varchar, char,... or a number?

Comment: @NaveTseva I have asked for the *value*, not for the type. Are you aware that showing us the value of `InsertQuery` string would make it obvious what's wrong?

Comment: In the sql it is date/time type

Comment: There is at least one problem there - TimeSpan.ToString() returns `00:00:00` (the format not the value) by default - can `DateTime` in SQL even parse a date from this string? (looks like it can! :)) - at least show your actual values or parameterise your query

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic The value is "TrackDuration =02:30:00

Comment: Give us all a hint and run this through the debugger then put a watch on `InsertQuery` and paste the actual value of the generated SQL string

Comment: No. that is not the value of `InsertQuery`, 100%. I am not sure if it would help if I ask what is the value of `InsertQuery` for the fourth time.

Comment: I don't understand why you could use Datetime for such value (as Timespan), datetime is a point in time where timespan is a span of time. they are different.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic sorr, I fix this now

Comment: I updates my question with the values @ZdeslavVojkovic

Comment: @Nave Tseva, once again, you should post your table structure (columns type) as if the values are not [convertible] column types, the query will fail.

Comment: @KingKing I updated my question, pleas review it

Comment: @Nave Tseva Are you sure there is a type of boolean in SQL Server? It is called exactly as bit, not boolean. Please confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'02:30:00'  is not a correct value for **datetime** DB field, AFAIK. The default format is controlled by [date format setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx).

Additionally, '20130412' should work in any case, but for datetime field. You need to format the `TrackDuration` correctly or use [`CAST/CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). As `TimeSpan` doesn't contain date part (it represents a duration and not a point in time), you can only make it up (e.g. prepend "20100101") but that is an awful hack.

The proper solution is to use the correct DB field type.

'02:30:00' might work if the field was of `time` type. Please read some more about [time types in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

Even better, why don't you use plain integer for the duration in seconds? The duration is not a date anyway.

The much bigger issue is that you are concatenating strings to set the command text, which opens you for SQL injection attack. If I name the racing track `a';DROP TABLE tblTracks;--` your database is toast:

```
UPDATE tblTracks SET TrackLength=35, 
                     TrackDuration='02:30:00', 
                     TrackName='a';DROP TABLE tblTracks;-- ...
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! The duretion is hours/minuts.
If the duration will be string, is it work?

Comment: no, as your field is **DATE**time but you don't have a date, only duration. please follow the links in my answer.

Comment: @Nave Tseva Your table structure is not well designed, as you said IsCircular and ForBeginners are type of string, but it should be re-designed as type of bit. And the duration as Zdeslav said should be number calculated in seconds, or time (not datetime) if you want to use Timespan in C# code.

Comment: @KingKing Thank you, but i think that that's what I did: 
"               TimeSpan TrackDuration =TimeSpan.Parse( Request.Form["TrackDuration"].ToString());

Comment: Yes, you want to use Timespan, so re-design your TrackDuration column type and change it to time (datetime won't work)

Comment: @NaveTseva TimeSpan is a duration. DateTime is a fixed point in time. You can't mix them like that. You SQL field is datetime - you can't assign duration to it. It would bi similar to assigning an `int[]` to an `int` variable. You have to change the DB field type.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic +1 for your update, it looks better for the asker to follow, but there is still not response from him. His problem is in fact simple. NaveTseva, you should use Parameters of SqlCommand object to add parameters for the command, it should be made familiar with.